# How to build LINQ-query dynamically based on array of input arguments

Tags: linq

I have next LINQ-query which imitates full outer join on two datatables

```
(From r1 As datarow In dt1
 From r2 As datarow In dt2
 Where
     r1(0).Equals( r2(0) ) And
     r1(1).Equals( r2(1) ) And
     math.abs(CDec(r1(2))-CDec(r1(3))).Equals( math.abs(CDec(r2(2))-CDec(r2(3))) )
 Select r1.ItemArray.Concat(r2.itemarray).ToArray).toarray
```

adn returns Object[][].

My desire is to pass `{"r1(0)", "r2(0)", "r1(1)", "r2(1)", "math.abs(cdec(r1(2))-cdec(r1(3)))", "math.abs(cdec(r2(2))-cdec(r2(3)))"}` into WHERE-clause of LINQ-query pattern.

In case of passing `{"math.abs(cdec(r1(2))-cdec(r1(3)))", "math.abs(cdec(r2(2))-cdec(r2(3)))"}` LINQ-query should become like this:

```
(From r1 As datarow In dt1
 From r2 As datarow In dt2
 Where
     math.abs(CDec(r1(2))-CDec(r1(3))).Equals( math.abs(CDec(r2(2))-CDec(r2(3))) )
 Select r1.ItemArray.Concat(r2.itemarray).ToArray).toarray
```

Optionally I can pass String `"r1(0), r2(0); r1(1), r2(1); math.abs(cdec(r1(2))-cdec(r1(3))), math.abs(cdec(r2(2))-cdec(r2(3)))"`.

I would be very grateful for your help.

**HUGE UPDATE**

Trying out this (based on System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) expression

```
dt1.AsEnumerable.AsQueryable
.Join(
      dt2.AsEnumerable,
      "new(get_Item(0) as Column0, get_Item(1) as Column1)",
      "new(get_Item(0) as Column0, get_Item(1) as Column1)",
      "new(outer.get_Item(4) as Column4, inner.get_Item(4) as Column4)"
     )
```

throws "Ambiguous match found." exception.

Also changing my expression from previous to

```
in_dt1.AsEnumerable.AsQueryable
.Join(
      in_dt2.AsEnumerable,
      "new(math.abs(cdec(get_Item(2) as Column2)-cdec(get_Item(3) as Column3)) as A)",
      "new(math.abs(cdec(get_Item(2) as Column2)-cdec(get_Item(3) as Column3)) as A)",
      "new(outer.get_Item(4) as Column4, inner.get_Item(4) as Column4)"
)
```

throws "')' or ',' expected" exception.

Comment: Your first dynamic try has `Column4` twice, which causes the ambiguous match, but it still won't work if you fix that error, because the return type from `Join` is `IQueryable<DataRow>` which your anonymous object isn't.

Comment: Your second example fails because `as` is used to name members of an anonymous class, and you can't use it in the middle of expressions, as well as `cdec` not being a defined C# method - C# uses `Convert.ToDecimal`. After that, you get the same problem as try #1 - `Join` returns `IQueryable<DataRow>` which your anonymous object is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correct the type errors and use the correct functions, you can get this to work:

```
var ans = ((IQueryable)dt1.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable())
             .Join(dt2.AsEnumerable(),
                   "new(get_Item(0) as c0, get_Item(1) as c1, math.abs(Convert.ToDecimal(get_Item(2))-Convert.ToDecimal(get_Item(3))) as c2)",
                   "new(get_Item(0) as c0, get_Item(1) as c1, math.abs(Convert.ToDecimal(get_Item(2))-Convert.ToDecimal(get_Item(3))) as c2)",
                   "new(outer.get_Item(4) as Column0, inner.get_Item(4) as Column1)"
               );
```

Dynamic LINQ doesn't support creating arrays but using Reflection you can convert an object into an array - I am not sure I would recommend this, however.

With the following extension methods for converting any object into an array of a provided type (which must be castable):

```
public static class TypeExt {
    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
        t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();
}

public static class MemberInfoExt {
    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case MethodInfo mi:
                return mi.Invoke(srcObject, null);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}

public static class ObjectExt {
    public static T[] ToArray<T>(this object obj, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) {
        List<T> ans;
        if (obj is IDictionary<string, object> id)
            ans = id.Values.Select(v => (T)v).ToList();
        else {
            ans = new List<T>();
            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetPropertiesOrFields(bf)) {
                try {
                    ans.Add((T)prop.GetValue(obj));
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                    // ignore inaccessible properties
                }
            }
        }
        return ans.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can convert the anonymous objects created into an `string[]`:

```
var ans2 = ans.AsEnumerable()
              .Select(v => ((object)v).ToArray<string>())
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, this query is working, thanks a lot.
Also extended output argument up to 10 column succesfully.
But ans.FirstOrDefault.GetType.Name returns "<>f__AnonymousType1`10" and equals [{ Column0 = 17.01.20, Column1 = 00116071, Column2 = 10218.9, Column3 = 0, Column4 = smth1, Column5 = 17.01.20, Column6 = 00116071, Column7 = 0, Column8 = 10218.9, Column9 = smth2}] - any guesses about converting that to an array of strings?

Comment: @hazardantony I don't recommend it, but I added code to convert an anonymous object into a `string[]`. It now feels to me like you may be using the wrong tools to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the code!
I managed to do it by myself via using Regex to get rid of junk (pattern "Column.* = ").